Pattern in orthogonal vectors.
Link. I tried Gram-Schmidt orthogonalization to the first column vector with orthonormal basis vectors. But I couldn't come up with the pattern. Is there any possible way to reach this pattern?

What exactly is your question? Are you trying to prove that Will's pattern provides an orthonormal basis? Are you asking for some insight into how Will came up with such a pattern? Or, are you struggling to figure out what Will's pattern will produce in general?

@TheoBendit yes I am trying to figure out if there's any algorithm to reach the same pattern.

Yes, trivially, you could follow the Gram-Schmidt algorithm on the orthogonal basis, to return the same orthogonal basis. But this won't give you any insight into how Will generated the orthogonal basis in the first place, which sounds it sounds like is the essence of your question. The issue is, Will probably just used some intuition, followed his nose, and came up with an ad-hoc pattern that worked.

Not exactly. I'm more saying that we don't have a well-defined starting point. If we start from the answer, then getting to the answer is easy. But, where else is it acceptable to start from? Providing such a basis will always require some measure of creativity, as you are asked to produce an orthonormal basis with certain conditions, and these bases are very, very far from unique. Will used his creativity. I provided another (less creative) possibility in the comments. Siong provided yet another possibility.

@TheoBendit I guess. I don't know, it feels a bit natural that there might be a clever way to represent this;)

I remain sceptical, but we'll see if anyone answers (perhaps Will himself).
